# Scheduled Tasks not running - Coldfusion Server Administration

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-10, cfhttp, coldfusion-7

I have a series of scheduled tasks that all run at various times of the day. Since the migration from Coldfusion version 7 to 10, these tasks have stopped running.

When I check the box, that outputs the results to a file, I get a text file that says nothing more than "Connection Failure". I have tried everything imaginable regarding the username and password for the task. It makes no difference.  When I run the CFM page in my browser, the
page works correctly and generates an email just like it should. I just
can't make it run as a scheduled event.

Comment: can you once run from Scheduled Task forcely.

Comment: @Ramki I tried running the file directly and it works. But it is not working when test run in the cfadmin and at the schedule task running time.

Comment: I'll comment here as well. Could it be antivirus/firewall/other protection program running on the web-server not recognizing the cf-process and stopping it?

Comment: What exactly do your scheduled tasks do? Shot in the dark, but .. I noticed your tags include `cfhttp`, so I am wondering it it is related. Are your scheduled tasks performing `cfhttp` calls? Shot in the dark, but any chance *that* is what is failing, rather than the scheduled task itself? Also, did you check all of your CF log files for errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the scheduled task folder has any check for the session or anything? I mean is the scheduled task folder is accessible without login? Please try with removing all the redirect rules for the application. That might work.

Answer (score 1):

For me the requests were timing out. I increased the timeout in the administrator and that solved it. Doing a cfhttp in a test file and dumping the results helped me troubleshoot it.