# Coldfusion scheduled task not working in CF10-AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, migration, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-10

This is the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173133/scheduled-tasks-not-running-coldfusion-server-administration).

We have migrated from CF 7 to CF 10. We made everything work but the scheduled tasks. We have created scheduled task to run some files. **The server setup is AWS.** The files are working correctly when we run it directly and it is not working at the scheduled time. We are not getting any mails from these files. We have some logs for this and it adds log entry as "Connection Failure". Any help would be appreciated.